# constraint error MySQL 5.6 while creating two tables with one foreign key

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I need a little help with the SQL code below.  I am using MySQL 5.6:

```
CREATE TABLE REGION   (
REGION_CD       varchar(200),               
REGION_NAME     Text (50),      
Constraint REGION_PK Primary Key (REGION_CD(200)));

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID         long (50)
CUST_NAME       Text (50), 
REGION_CD       varchar (2), 
Constraint Customer_PK Primary Key 
(CUST_ID(50)), 
Constraint C_REGION_CD_FK 
Foreign Key (REGION_CD) 
References REGION);
```

This is my error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(50) CUST_NAME Text (50), REGION_CD varchar (2), Constraint
>   Customer_PK Pr' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields involved in foreign key relationships must have identical type-definitions. You don't have that:

```
REGION_CD       varchar(200),               
REGION_CD       varchar (2),
```

The "foreign" field can be nullable while the parent field isn't, but otherwise type and size definitions MUST be the same.

The reason: since your parent record has a longer field limit, you could have something like `ab12`, `ab34`, `ab56`. If your child record has `ab` in it, WHICH of those `12`, `34`, `56` variants should match?